# Change order of markup for exposed views filter

Tags: views, forms

I have a search box on my homepage, and to style it correctly I need the button to come before the text box in the markup. The current block code looks like the following.

```
<form action="/drupal-7.22/search" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-commerce-search-page" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="views-exposed-form">
  <div class="views-exposed-widgets clearfix">
          <div id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-search_api_views_fulltext">
                  <label for="edit-search-api-views-fulltext">
            Search for products          </label>
                        <div class="views-widget">
          <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-api-views-fulltext">
 <input type="text" id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext" name="search_api_views_fulltext" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" class="form-text required error">
</div>
        </div>
              </div>
                    <div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">
      <input type="submit" id="edit-submit-commerce-search" name="" value="Go!" class="form-submit">    </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div></form>
```

I've looked at `hook_form_alter()` and a few template files, but I think that's the wrong way to do it and I'm far from an expert.

I wouldn't mind being able to clean up that tangle of divs too!

Comment: Have you tried `hook_form_alter()`?  Specifically,  [`#weight`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#weightval)

Comment: I've looked at #weight, but I don't see a way of applying it to a specific <div> via hook_form_alter(), as changing the weight of the #submit element does nothing - its parent <div> needs changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up a test environment and doing some digging, `#weight` isn't going to do you any good.  This is what I did to move the button:

Create a new document in your theme folder and name it `views-exposed-form--commerce-search-page.tpl.php`.  Now, copy the contents of `sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-exposed-form.tpl.php` to your new file.  Next find

```
<div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">
  <?php print $button; ?>
</div>
```

And move it wherever you please, for my test I moved it directly below:

```
<div class="views-exposed-widgets clearfix">
```

which made it the first item in the form.  Finally, clear the cache and reload the page.

Further, you should look into the [Theme Developer module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) if you're not using it already.  It is very handy for figuring out which `.tpl.php` file you should create, or which `_preprocess()` function should be used, to effect the element you're targeting.

Comment: Just came back to say this is the solution I found, after 4life pointed me in the right direction. Accepted this answer as it's more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own views-exposed-form.tpl.php file and move the submit button to the top, or add a class to it and use css to float left and right. This however would affect all exposed filter on your site.

If you want to alter the form you should use the function

```
function MODULENAME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state)
```

Your best option is however to try manipulating it with css.

Answer (score 0):

You have add them in

$form['#info']['filter-byline-names']['value'] = 'abc';
$form['#info']['filter-byline-profile-type']['value'] = 'efg';

where **abc**, **efg** are the newly added form element

```
$form['abc'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield' ,
        '#title' => 'ABC' ,
      );
      $form['efg'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select' ,
        '#title' => 'Profile Type',
        '#options' => array('asdasd','rajveer','gangwar'),
      );
```